# Selecting all django models with a blank ImageField

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=512,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In my code I can get all people who have no name like so:

```
Person.objects.filter(name__isnull=True)
```

How can I do the same with images and find a list of all people without an image stored in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out images are never `null`, so the following is required to find any models without an image:

```
Person.objects.filter(image='')
```